# Error on Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a timer. I want the timer to count down the count up. This all works. However, the timer needs to go through a bunch of times in different rows but should NOT move to the next time until a button is pressed. This will allow me to extract times that went over the countdown.

Any ideas? (I am using the finish as a button, all it does is black a cell). I was hoping that when I did that the times would reset and go to the next column.

```
Sub GoGo()
```

Public GoGo As Boolean

GoGo = True

End Sub

Sub Runn()

Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long

```
        For i = 23 To 32


           DoEvents
            If GoGo = True Then

                If Cells(i, 1) <> 0 Then

             Range("B5").Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
             Range("E5").Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
             Range("E11").Value = Range("C33").Value

             Application.Run ("Realcount")
             Application.Run ("Realcount2")

            End If
            End If



            Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do Range(i, 2) or Range(i, 3).  Did you means Cells(i, 2)?

Comment: That fixed it. Do you have any insight on how to go through the for loop then NOT go to the next "i" until a button is pressed.

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to throw up a MsgBox at each point you want to wait for the user to click.

Comment: Using a `Do...While` loop, public variable and `DoEvents` to allow a button to set the public variable within the loop's.

Comment: The problem is the code you cant ssee are timers. It counts down and counts up. A button is nice because it can be pressed at any time. A messagebox on the other hand is prompted by something.

Comment: This is my new code with the DoEvents and public variable but I cannot get it to work. I apolgize for the code, I don't know how to format it in comments!