# Have macro for loop, need to throttle and only move to next i when a new button is pressed

Tags: excel, vba

Pretty much I have a loop that I want to run through, however I don't want it to go to the next "i" until a button is pressed. My code is as follows. I believe my trouble is the location of the "If GoGo" but I have tried it in many places.

```
Sub GoGo()
    Public GoGo As Boolean
    GoGo = True
End Sub

Sub Runn()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long

    For i = 23 To 32
        DoEvents
        If GoGo = True Then
            If Cells(i, 1) <> 0 Then
                 Range("B5").Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
                 Range("E5").Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
                 Range("E11").Value = Range("C33").Value
                 Application.Run ("Realcount")
                 Application.Run ("Realcount2")
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Repeated post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16044743/error-on-method-range-of-object-global-failed

Comment: Why not turn your loop into a queue? Don't wait for something to let it continue, have something to make it continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Public GoGo As Boolean

Sub GoGoProc()
    GoGo = True
End Sub

Sub Runn()
    Dim lastrow As Long, i As Long

    i = 23

    Do
        DoEvents
        If GoGo = True Then
            If Cells(i, 1) <> 0 Then
                Range("B5").Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
                Range("E5").Value = Cells(i, 3).Value
                Range("E11").Value = Range("C33").Value
                Application.Run ("Realcount")
                Application.Run ("Realcount2")
            End If
            i = i + 1
            GoGo = False
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

Instead of using a loop, the best way I can think of is using a modeless userform (*so that you want work with the `Workbook/Worksheet` at the same time*) with a `Next` button. The `Next` button will increment the row value and then run the code. This way you will not keep Excel busy if you had to leave say for a cup of coffee ;)

Create Userform (UNTESTED) which should look like this

[image]

Paste this code in the userform

```
'~~> Next Button
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("B5").Value = Cells(rw, 2).Value
    Range("E5").Value = Cells(rw, 3).Value
    Range("E11").Value = Range("C33").Value

    Application.Run ("Realcount")
    Application.Run ("Realcount2")

    rw = rw + 1
End Sub

'~~> Canecel Button
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Create a Module and paste this code there

```
Public rw As Long

Sub Launch()
    rw = 23
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

To run your code, you can either run `Sub Launch()` directly or create a Command Button (*Form Control - I guess that is what you are using*) on your worksheet and assign `Sub Launch()` to it.

Comment: It keeps saying "ambigious name". The code looks good but I cannot test it! I will try to google what that means..

Comment: It looks like that occurs if you had used the name before, but I have tried different random words, no luck.

Comment: Looks better, so do you reccomend I set a button linked to the GoGoProc() macro then click it for each i.                                         Also you've been amazing help.

Comment: Quick question. After it enters the loop, wouldn't you want to set the value of `GoGo` to `False` so that it doesn't move to the next `i` until the `GoGoProc()` is run?

Comment: Also instead of looping have you thought about using a userform to run your macro with a `NEXT` Button? That ways you will not keep Excel busy with your `Do Loop` Imagine if you had to go for a cup of coffee in between?

Comment: I would love to do a next button, I am decent with excel but have been having a LOT of trouble with this workbook. A next button would be IDEAL. is there any input you have with it?

Comment: Post Updated. Refresh the page

Comment: Siddharth this works amazing, the second time through the Application.Run doesn't trigger for some reason but you have helped me get past a road block big time! Hope this premotes poeple to hire you cause you deserve it. If i wansnt still a poor student I would!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28337/discussion-between-thommy-s-and-siddharth-rout)